# Image is not the same quality than the original image

Tags: android, image, android-layout, imageview, blur

I am building an android application and I have issues with images.

I use this image:

[image: http://imgur.com/DqUlae8]

and here's my result:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/AnmUpH8.png]

As you can see, the first image is pretty clear but not on my android application. The image is blurry.

I tried using an ImageView and ImageButton but same result for both.

Any solution to this?

Comment: The original image is only 128x128 pixels, what size in pixels do you show it on the device? I guess it is scaled up quite a bit.

Comment: I can't notice differences... are there?

Comment: @DerGolem I am with you. I have pretty great vision and I am not really seeing a resolution issue from those links.

Comment: @Henry 128x128 image which I would like to show the same or smaller

Comment: @DerGolem look at the center of the image, you will notice it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why the image quality is blurry?**

Simply because the image size and DPI is low. If you use a small images on a large device, the low resolution image will have to expand to the size in the ImageView or ImageButton property (layout_width and layout_height).

Let's pretend we need to use a small device phone like the Nexus One. This has a resolution of 480 pixels by 800 pixels.

[image: nexusone]

If you have an image that is 128 pixels by 128 pixels within 100% scale, you will put 3 images side by side.

Let me demonstrate you with this example. I am using two images:

https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/310718/fiddle_instrument_music_violin_icon#size=128

https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/310718/fiddle_instrument_music_violin_icon#size=512

Here's the test:

[image: screen]

**Left Side**

I use the 128x128 first, then the 512x512 using the `layout_width` and `layout_height` with `128xp` as the value. (This is not recommended, just for test purposes).

As you can see, they are very similar in quality. Which make sense since both are sized at 128x128 pixels.

**Right side**

I used the same 128x128 first, then the 512x512 using the `layout_width` and `layout_height` with `130dp` as the value. Now you can see the difference in quality (look at the strings). With high density pixels, the 128x128 will have to be stretched and the 512x512 will have to be shrunk. This way, the 128x128 will lose quality image and makes it blurry.

**Conclusion**

Make sure the images you use have a higher resolution and a high DPI and make sure you put them in their respective folders. (`drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, 
`drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`,`drawable-xxhdpi`­).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're inadvertently upscaling it. Try adding `android:scaleType="center"` to your ImageView's XML code. If it's then sharp, but not displaying at the size you need, you'll need a higher resolution source.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the images to PNG i think have better quality in that picture. And check the size